# Windows 10 memory fragmentation on long application run

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-fragmentation

We are facing a memory fragmentation issue in our 32 bit app (C++ and WPF based). when we run it for 100 hrs. as part of automated test. Application crashes after running AST for ~14 hrs.

We use CRT heap with LFH policy (Low fragment Heap)  exclusively enabled in `Main()`. Problem is coming on windows 10 platform. No issue on Windows 8 platform with same set of our application binaries. We completed 100 hrs. run for test in windows 8 platform.

We create a large block heap in `Main()` method and this heap we use for specific purpose when we need a large amount of memory and we are managing it in our code. From Virtual Memory Statistics logs we can see that initial virtual memory allocation is 1.79 GB.

After 14 hrs. of automated test run : on windows 10

```
   Combined Available = 1590176752( 1516.511 MB)
   Combined Max Available = 3989504( 3.805 MB)
   Combined Frag Percent = 99.75%
   CRT:sum_alloc          = 2737569144(98.50%, 2610.749 MB)
   CRT:max_alloc          =    4458496(          4.252 MB)
   CRT:allocAverageSize   =       9043
   CRT:num_free_blocks    =      37813
   CRT:sum_free           =   22620888( 0.81%,  21.573 MB)
   CRT:max_free           =     514104(          0.490 MB)

   VM:sum_free = 1581957120(36.83%,1508.672 MB)
   VM:max_free = 10321920( 9.844 MB)
```

On windows 8 for 100 hrs.

- Combined Available     = 1881204960(       1794.057 MB)
- Combined Max Available = 1734127616(       1653.793 MB)
- Combined Frag Percent  =       7.82%
- VM:sum_free           = 1845817344(42.98%,1760.309 MB)
- VM:max_free           = 1734127616(       1653.793 MB)

We are using ADPlus and (debugging tools for Windows, Windbg and DebugDiag) tool to collect memory dumps at interval of 3 hrs.

Is there any setting or flag which I need to enable or anything I have to do withy code, using VS2010.

Application is based on Windows 10 LTSB 64 bit (which is very specific Enterprise OS version for windows 10, gives stability and security)

Comment: I've had to take memory fragmentation into consideration once. The best solution we found was to avoid dynamic allocation of multiple small quantities (when possible). There is no magic flag to set.

Comment: As I once struggled with allocation of many small objects, I overloaded `operator new` (and `operator delete`) to allocate from memory banks. Thereby, memory banks had fixed size and were filled consecutively from beginning. Deleting memory just decremented a resp. ref-counter in the corr. bank until it reached 0. At this point the bank was just given back to a pool. On "modern" Windows/VS, the heap management has been improved and I do not use anymore this code. Google e.g. "C++ allocation memory pool" may help to find something appropriate if interested...

Comment: Consider using multiple, different memory pools.  For example, one pool for managing small size allocations, another for larger size allocations.

Comment: test it under Win10 v1709, here MS fixed some memory related issues.

Comment: Application is based on Windows 10 LTSB (which is very specific Enterprise OS version for windows 10, gives stability and security)

Comment: 20171128 18:09:08.000000 [Windows]           Category:Application Severity:ERROR Details:XXXXX:"EventName: errh:NewFailure FieldServiceText: Failed to allocate memory. File,LineNumber: XXXXX.cpp,479 StationName: DP DateTime: 20171128180908023 ProcessName: XXXXX.exe Additional Details: Size of malloc or new attempted: 2,097,667DiagnosticCode: 0001.DT3G6P92.0

Comment: last LTSB is 1607 and doesn't include the fix only the last 1709 has memory related fixes. So test it in a VM with the 1709

Comment: Hi Andre, My one question is that is this 1709 version is an update or its a new version itself of windows10 , Is this version update applied to windows 10 LTSB also ? I am sorry if you think that I am not understanding but I am seriously confused, one of the Microsoft guy also asked me to use this version but I am just confuse because we use windows 10 LTSB ?

Comment: 1709 is a new version, no update to LTSB. Next LTSB will be either 1903 or 1909 depending on when Microsoft relases the next LTSB in 2019.

Comment: I guess I encounter the same problem ,on Windows 10 21H1 . I run a java program, there is 128GB RAM, after some operations, errors like "Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 16626221056 bytes for Failed to commit area from 0x0000027f04000000 to 0x00000282e3000000 of length 16626221056." The workaround is a reboot. Another run just after reboot, there's no problem. I'm no yet written a reproduce steps(I don't want to contribute M$ for free). The java program run on Linux has no such problem.

Comment: the reproduce step is not tested, but I guess it's like this:
suppose you have 128GB RAM,
1) in a program you alloc as many as possible of 16GB memory block.
2) exit the program. the free memory return to 100GB+
3) lauch another program alloc 17GB memory block. -> fail